# RangeError (index): Invalid value. Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: list, flutter, null

```dart
Row(         
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       
   children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(
                  password[0] == null ? unchangedPassword : changedPassword, //Error happens here
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
             ),
        )
    ]
)
```

Can someone please explain why I can't write an if statement that checks if the value at the index is equal to a null value?

Comment: what is `password`? Add more details..

Comment: List<int> password = [];

Answer (score 3):

Use `password.isEmpty` instead of `password[0] == null`

Answer (score 1):

password[0] doesn't exist.
It appears password is a List

you could do password[0] == null if it was a map, but it's not.  It's a list.  That value doesn't exist.  It's not null.  It doesn't exist.  So it blows up.

Why doesn't it exist?  Because the memory wasn't allocated.  Flutter will allocated the memory automatically when you need it.  If you do password.add(value), then password[0] will exist at that point. But since you're getting the range error you haven't used password.add

For lists, use password.isNotEmpty or password.length == 0;

Answer (score 0):

I have been also facing this issue and following checking solved my issue

```
Text("${(subjects.isEmpty) ? "" : subjects.name}"),
```